Pointcloud2 in RVIZ2 using tf2_ros::buffer and lookupTransform
tf2_ros::Buffer tfBuffer;
 tf2_ros::TransformListener tfListener(tfBuffer);
 

 rclcpp::Rate rate(30.0);
 while(rclcpp::ok())
 {
  static geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped transformStamped;
  geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped newtransformStamped;
  try{
  //newtransformStamped = tfBuffer2.lookupTransform(sFrameId, sChildFrameId, &time);
  newtransformStamped = tfBuffer.lookupTransform(sFrameId , sChildFrameId, rclcpp::Time(0));
  }
  catch (tf2::TransformException &ex) {
         rclcpp::spin_some(node);
         rate.sleep();
         continue;
       }

Hello guys,
i have to port a ROS1 Software to ROS2. Now i have to bring a Pointcloud2 into RVIZ2 and I have problems to do so. I already ported a Node that publishes the Pointcloud, but now i need to transform it from a "world" Frame to a "child-Frame". I create this parent frame world also in the .cpp where this upper code is from. This inserted Code is from ROS1 and i get an Error at the first line tf2_ros::Buffer tfBuffer;. It says that there is no default constructor and i am not really sure how i should port this into ROS2. My first intention was to make a class for this one but the thing is that i want it to be near as ROS1 as it gets. So do you have any tips how i can easily get this to work?
Thanks in advance!

    std::shared_ptr<tf2_ros::Buffer> tf_buffer_;
 std::shared_ptr<tf2_ros::TransformListener> tf_listener_;

 tf_buffer_ = std::make_shared<tf2_ros::Buffer>(node->get_clock());
 tf_listener_ = std::make_shared<tf2_ros::TransformListener>(*tf_buffer_);
  LOG() <<"Transform State 2"<<sRosNode<<std::endl;
 rclcpp::Rate rate(30.0);
 while(rclcpp::ok())
 {
  static geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped transformStamped;
  geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped newtransformStamped;
  
    LOG() <<"Transform State 3"<<sRosNode<<std::endl;
  try{
  //newtransformStamped = tfBuffer2.lookupTransform(sFrameId, sChildFrameId, &time);
  newtransformStamped = tf_buffer_->lookupTransform(sFrameId , sChildFrameId, tf2::TimePointZero);
    LOG() <<"Transform State 4"<<sRosNode<<std::endl;
  }
  catch (tf2::TransformException &ex) {
          LOG() <<"Couldnt transform"<<sRosNode<<std::endl;
         rclcpp::spin_some(node);
         rate.sleep();
         continue;
       }

I tried it that way and it works. Maybe somebody needs it in the future. ;)
